# Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never' in Typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-eslint

When I write some code, I have some problems like that:

```
function getObjectKeys<T extends object>(object: T) {
    return Object.keys(object) as (keyof T)[]
}

const props = {
    propA: 100,
    propB: 'text'
}

const store = { ...props }

getObjectKeys(props).forEach((key) => {
    store[key] = props[key]
})
```

reported some errors:

```
const store: {
    propA: number;
    propB: string;
}
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
```

when I write like this:

```
getObjectKeys(props).forEach((key) => {
    if (key === 'propA') {
        store[key] = props[key]
    } else if (key === 'propB'){
        store[key] = props[key]
    } else {
        store[key] = props[key]
    }
})
```

It can work but not so good. how to solve them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlying issue is a type safety improvement implemented by [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) when doing assignments to [unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of object properties.  When faced with code like

```
type PropKeys = keyof typeof props; // "propA" | "propB"
getObjectKeys(props).forEach((key: PropKeys) => {    
    store[key] = ... // what is allowable here
});
```

the compiler sees that `key` is of the union type `"propA" | "propB"`.  It doesn't know whether `key` is `"propA"` or `"propB"`, so to be safe, it only wants to allow assignments which would work no matter which it turns out to be.  That means the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of the property types.  Since these types are `number` and `string`, the intersection is `number & string`, which reduces to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type) because no values are of both types.  And so the compiler cannot allow *any* assignment to `store[key]`.

The fix in this case is to replace values of union types with values of [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) types that are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to the union.  When the key or object is generic, the safety check from microsoft/TypeScript#30769 is not applied.  This is potentially unsafe, but it is allowed, as mentioned [in this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769#issuecomment-498428559).  It looks like this:

```
getObjectKeys(props).forEach(<K extends PropKeys>(key: K) => {
  store[key] = props[key]; // okay
})
```

That compiles with no error, and is as close to type safe as you can get.  If you change the assignment to something definitely unsafe, like copying `props.propA` into `store[key]`, you will get a warning again:

```
getObjectKeys(props).forEach(<K extends PropKeys>(key: K) => {  
  store[key] = props.propA; // error!
})
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQPICMBWroDSqAngM4A8AKoqgB5SpgAmpicu+UAfABTt7QAXIkoBKRAG8AUIkQAndCDlJsAqADoA1iVJ8O0cQENWPbcTjARogNoBdKQF8pUiAlJREABzlxPrALySMl4+ngCCwgCMAAzRADTB3r4AQsIA5Az0aY7OLm4e7nAKiIESiOoVSX6ITlJQxJ6oiAAKoURkJYhmFoj1jT1VpADcUmiY+lDtuoOi6sBFAKKGEAAWPOQENPSMLC1tOrxmwgTi-lySssGFCtZmtp2D6lVhQ4gA9G80cj5yAIRXUCKqFuJHugUGIOIthGDlEUiAA)

Comment: thx so so much! u totally answered my confusion. At first I also tried generics, but the syntax failed. now i get the right situation : )

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid using `object` in TS. Its not recommend or ideal solution instead use `Record<..., ...>`.

Target object `store` must to be `Record<string, any>` to get your code working since TS don't know which properties will be added ahead of time.

```js
function getObjectKeys<T extends Record<string, any>>(object: T) {
    return Object.keys(object) as (keyof T)[]
}

const props = {
    propA: 100,
    propB: 'text'
}

const store: Record<string, any> = {}

getObjectKeys(props).forEach((key) => {
    store[key] = props[key]
})
```

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZQPICMBWroDSqAngM4A8AKoqgB5SpgAmpiASvnAE5PmlRcYYZABpEAQzDEAfNIAUcXPigAuRJQCUiAN4BYAFCIjiLuhBck2PNAB0AaxKkFS6FvGs5D4nGDqNAbQBdAwBfAwMIBH5EAAcuOBjWAF4dA2NY+JiAQTUARgAGfJE04ziEgCE1AHIGeirQ8P1IsGj+blQ1DkiePgEhUQkpaUQU7TD9AzRMFygiMjkyxI0bYG4AUXEIAAs5TxItJOG9Q2M2038vQJGMhNILkmD9EI0DIA)

Comment: "You should avoid using extends object in TS. Its not recommend or ideal solution instead use Record<..., ...>" This isn't true. `extends object` is fine; where do you see that it's not recommended?  Not recommended by whom?  In any case, changing it to `extends Record<string, any>` doesn't do anything to fix the problem.

Comment: @jcalz see [this and example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-2.html#object-type)  it was introduced to represents the non-primitive types so you should not use it to for custom types.

Comment: I remember reading something that was explaining briefly why we should avoid but I can't find it as of now.

Comment: There was an ESLint rule that discouraged using `object`, but ESLint is a third party tool... and nobody from the TS team ever said this.  It's hard to consume a value of type `object`, but that doesn't apply to `T extends object`, which is 100% useful and recommended.  If you can find an authoritative source that can explain why `T extends object` should be removed, you should include it in your answer.  If you leave it unattributed then it reads like opinion, and since it is factually incorrect, I will downvote if its left there.